# replace html tags dosn't work true (preg_replace)

Tags: php

Hi i use this preg_replace :

```
preg_replace("/<font(.*?)>$key2<\/font>/","<b>$key2</b>",$out,1)
```

But it replace more than this pattern ! some times many lines of input remove whit this function ! I need to replace just first case
i need to replace exactly this :

```
<font style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through' >$key2</font>
```

Whit :

```
<b>$key2</b>
```

Comment: If you need to replace a static string, why use regex? Just use simple string search. If you need regex for HTML tags, that's a very complex topic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Do you have fixed `<font>` style for all?

Comment: Have you considered using a DOM͜ pa̡r͏ser̵?

Comment: @BM When i use above string dostn't work or show error .

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi Yes .

Comment: Posting the answer shortly.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No Why ?

Comment: I think the problem with your regex is that it matches from the first `<font>` in strings like `<font ...>notkey2</font> ... <font ...>$key2</font> `. Maybe you can replace the non greedy dot (`.*?`) with a negated char group (`[^>]`).

Comment: @jh1711 I use preg_replace("/<font([^>]`)>$key2<\/font>/","<b>$key2</b>",$out,1) but dosn't work.

Comment: @creavaehahea, if you have the backtick ` in your php code, you need to delete. I wanted to use it for stackoverflow markup, but I needed several edits to get it right.

Comment: But Mohammed's answer looks even better, because str_replace is faster than preg_replace.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have fixed `<font>` style, follow the below steps. Use `str_replace`.

```
$in_val = "font style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through'";
echo str_replace("font style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through'","bold",$in_val); //instead of echoing, you can store it in a variable as well to use it further.
```

Now for the closing tag, use the below code.

```
$in_val_2 = '/font';
echo str_replace("/font","/bold",$in_val_2);
```

This will replace the code for you.